# make zsh ESC-Del delete components of a path and not the entire path

Tags: zsh

I'm moving from bash to zsh. In bash, esc-del deleted a component of a pathname; in zsh it deletes the entire pathname.

That is, if I have typed:

`cat /usr/local/bin/foobar`

and I hit ESC-DEL, in bash I ended up with:

`cat /usr/local/bin`

and with zsh I end up with:

`cat`

which is not what I want!

How do I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function

```
function kill-path-word()
{
  local words word spaces
   zle set-mark-command                 # save current cursor position ("mark")
   while [[ $LBUFFER[-1] == "/" ]] {
     (( CURSOR -= 1 ))                  # consume all trailing slashes
  }
  words=("${(s:/:)LBUFFER/\~/_}")       # split command line at "/" after "~" is replaced by "_" to prevent FILENAME EXPANSION messing things up
  word=$words[-1]                       # this is the portion from cursor back to previous "/"
  (( CURSOR -= $#word ))                # then, jump to the previous "/"
  zle exchange-point-and-mark           # swap "mark" and "cursor"
  zle kill-region                       # delete marked region
}
zle -N kill-path-word
```

Now, you can bind this function to e.g. `ESC+Del` by

```
bindkey "^[^[[3~" kill-path-word
```

Put both snippets to your `~/.zshrc` file, restart *zsh* and then `foo/bar/baz////` should be shortened to `foo/bar/` upon `ESC+Del`.

If you want also the training slash to be removed (as in you example), add the same `while ...` loop before `zle exchange-point-and-mark`.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. looks like it will work. What's `zle`

Comment: Actually, I want to bind it to ESC-backspace, not ESC-del. My error. Can you tell me how to do that? (I keep forgetting they are different.)

Comment: @vy32: _zle_ is the _zsh line editor_, the module responsible for editing the command line. For `ESC+Bkspace` try `^[^?` or `^[^H`.

Answer (score 2):

To extend mpy's answer, this is a version which does not consume the last 'cat /usr' all together, but deletes '/usr' and then 'cat '. It splits the $LBUFFER variable by a regex, which is more flexible than a single slash character.

```
function kill-path-word()
{
  local words word spaces
  zle set-mark-command                 # save current cursor position ("mark")
  words=($(grep -Eo '(/?[a-zA-Z1-9]+[\\ /]*)|([^a-zA-Z0-9])' <<< "$LBUFFER"))
  word=$words[-1]                       # this is the portion from cursor back to previous "/"
  while [[ $LBUFFER[-1] == " " ]] {
    (( CURSOR -= 1 ))                   # consume all trailing spaces - they don't get into the $word variable
  }
  (( CURSOR -= $#word ))                # then, jump to the previous "/"
  zle exchange-point-and-mark           # swap "mark" and "cursor"
  zle kill-region                       # delete marked region
}
zle -N kill-path-word
bindkey "^[^?" kill-path-word
```